# Extracting Data from Calendar on a Website

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, calendar

I have tried several methods but I unable to select a date on the calendar. This is the code I have written.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import time, re
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.get("https://fcainfoweb.nic.in/Reports/Report_Menu_Web.aspx")

html_source = driver.page_source
results=[]

driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_Rbl_Rpt_type_1"]""").click()
element_variation = driver.find_element_by_id ("ctl00_MainContent_Ddl_Rpt_Option1")
drp_variation = Select(element_variation)
drp_variation.select_by_visible_text("Daily Variation")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("ctl00_MainContent_Txt_FrmDate").send_keys("10/08/2019")
```

I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_Txt_FrmDate").send_keys("10/08/2019")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was an obvious error. Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: Nothing wrong with a second pair of eyes going over it.